# modify google spreadsheet using Ajax javascript only

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i am using javascript only to read and write values in google spreadsheet (private sheet using oAuth). I can successfully read the values but i am getting issue on modifying the sheet.
below is my code for updating the cell-

```
 $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
            headers: {
                Authorization: auth,
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                "access_token": auth,
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({ // generate from oAuthPlayground
                "access_token": auth,
                
                "range": "A1",
                "values": [
                    [
                        "32",
                        
                    ]
                ]
            
            
            }),              
            url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + sheetId + '/values/A2:batchUpdate?insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&valueInputOption=RAW',               
            success: function (r) {
                console.log(r)
            }, error: function (r) {
                console.log(r)
            }
        });
```

anybody can suggest what is the mistake. Again i am using only ajax not node.js or google script.

Comment: _i am getting issue on modifying the sheet_: which issue exactly?

Comment: it's not updating the cell.

Comment: Could you include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The question is not clear enough to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your showing script, I couldn't understand the following.

- What method in Sheets API do you want to use?
- Which do you want to put the value to the cell "A1" or "A2".
- I couldn't understand whether your access token can be used for updating the Spreadsheet.

From this situation, I guessed your current issue and your goal as follows.

- You want to put a value of `"32"` to a cell "A1" of the 1st sheet of the Spreadsheet.

  - In this case, "Method: spreadsheets.values.update" is used.
- Your access token can be used for updating the Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const auth = "Bearer ###"; // Please replace "###" with your access token.
const sheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

$.ajax({
  type: 'put',
  headers: { Authorization: auth, 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "values": [["32"]]
  }),
  url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + sheetId + '/values/A1?valueInputOption=RAW',
  success: function (r) {
    console.log(r)
  }, error: function (r) {
    console.log(r)
  }
});
```

- When this script is run, `"32"` is put to a cell "A1" of the 1st sheet of the Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: how i can update multiple cells value at one time? suppose i want to update cells A5,C5 and F5 all together.  i have done something lie this. but it doesn't work.*******
        type: 'put',
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " +auth, 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "range": "Users!A5",
            "values": [["ABC"]]
        },{
            "range": "Users!C5",
            "values": [["XYZ"]]
        }),
        url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+ sheetId + '?valueInputOption=RAW',

Comment: @user3369120 About your new question, I found [your posted new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75401633). So I posted an answer to it. Please confirm it.